# how to go one back line after EOF in c

Tags: c, file, eof

I am reading from a file in c, at the same time, I am writing to that file as per some sensor input.

But my sensor is interrupt based.

So, when there is no data, it does not write anything to that file.
But the code that is reading from file is reaching the EOF(end of file).

I want to write some code, that will read one line back, after reaching the EOF, so that if there will be any data from the sensor it will print.

If anyone is unable to understand my logic, please let me know, i can describe a bit more if required.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you show your code that is reading the lines currently? As a general approach, you could use `fseek` (or `seek`) to seek back in the file from the end an amount equal to the length of the last line read.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the length of the last line you read in a variable say `len`. Then [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to move the current read position back by one line.

```
fseek ( pFile , -1*len , SEEK_CUR );
```